# Do tag wiki excerpts need to remind people that tags can be combined?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

I just ran into a number of suggested tag wiki edits that included things like:

> This tag can also be used with tags such as [united-kingdom](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) and
>   also [friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends).

This sort of usage guidance makes sense in some contexts, but is it expected for all tag wikis?

Seems like it makes sense in cases where the additional tags add needed context, but in a lot of these cases it reads more like "you can use this tag in combination with other tags" which seems a little unnecessary and redundant.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the tag? Also, what was the entire tag wiki suggestion - was it more than just that line?

Comment: @HDE226868 https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tags/peer-pressure/info

Comment: Are you talking about Wikis or excerpts? That information is in the Wiki, not the excerpt.

Comment: "This tag can be used with others" is an obvious and unnecessary description to have. Reviewers, please do not let such wikis on our tags.

Comment: @Catija seeing them in review they're called "tag wiki excerpt" But it looks like the review category may cover both.

Comment: Yeah. The excerpt is the blurb that appears when you hover over the tag. The wiki is the "more information" that's longer and can contain markup.

Answer (score 3):

No. It's generally not recommended to do this.

The only time I make recommendations for tags in a tag excerpt is if a tag may be confused because the word can be used in two cases and the tag is only being used in one of them.

So, the tag would read something like:

> Use this tag for ____ if you're talking about ____ instead, please use the ____ tag.

The easiest example of actual usage I can think of is from cooking - British and American English is different, so we often let people know which tag to use instead. The "biscuit" tag wiki excerpt on [Cooking](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/) reads

> The often-savory quick bread that is common in the US, similar to a scone (UK). For the sweet dessert or snack, use "cookie". For digestive biscuits, use "digestive-biscuits".

Comment: Excerpts should be used not to remind people that the tag is indeed a tag - but rather to provide a brief explanation on what the tag's topic is about, and those quirky situations on when to use it. Your answer hits it on spot.